# How to find the number of chars in a string

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a program that will take two inputs: the first a char and the second a string. The program will then search through the string, one place at a time and keep track of how many times the char that the user input occurs in the string.

I cannot seem to find my mistake, but the `for` loop in my `CountCharacters` function seems to not be iterating. Can anyone offer any assistance?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int CountCharacters(char userChar, string userString) {
   int charCounter = 0;
   int i;
   
   for (i = 0; i > userString.length(); ++i) {
      if (userString.at(i) == userChar) {
       charCounter += 1;  
      }
   }
   return charCounter;
}


int main() {
   char userChar;
   string userString;
   
   cin >> userChar;
   getline(cin, userString);

   cout << CountCharacters(userChar, userString);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're probably not allowed to use it in this assignment, but... [`std::count`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count)

Comment: Probably a typo: `i > userString.length();` -> `i < userString.length();` `i`'s initial value of 0 will never be greater than the length of the string.

Comment: Learn to use debugger, it helps a lot in such case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @user4581301 pointed out, the condition in your for-loop doesn't make sense. If you set the value of `i = 0` and then check whether `i > userString.length()`, the boolean expression will always evaluate to false, since 0 will never be greater than the length of the inputted word. If your condition for your loop evaluates to false at the beginning itself, it will never start looping.

```cpp
for (i = 0; i < userString.length(); ++i)
```

Here, `i` is still `0`, but the boolean expression checks whether `i < userString.length()`. In the initial iteration, 0 will be less than the length of the inputted word, so the boolean expression will evaluate to true and the loop will run.

Answer (score 0):

If you're allowed to, use `std::count`.
If you're required to use a for loop, use a range based for loop.

```
// std::count version
int CountCharacters(const std::string& s, char c) {
    return std::count(s.begin(), s.end(), c);
}

// range based for loop version
int CountCharacters(const std::string& s, char c) {
    int count = 0;

    for (auto x : s)
        if (c == x) count++;

    return count;
}
```